# Small hole in front of cabinet

Tags: cabinets

There is a small hole approx. 2 mm in diameter in front of cabinet (see attached photo). Is there awayway to repair? It is made from MDF with a white finish.

Thank you.

Comment: What attached photo?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: fill the hole with white toothpaste

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to tell what's going on without a picture.... but I'll take a stab at it.

You need to find a wooden dowel, toothpick, skewer, etc. which is the same size as the hole and glue a piece of it in the hole. Then sand the protruding dowel, toothpick, skewer, etc. flat with the surface of the cabinet front and paint it to match.

If the hole is too small for the dowel,etc. you can fill the hole with wood filler, sand it flat and paint, or drill the hole to fit your dowel, sand and paint.

Answer (score 0):

2mm is so small that you could just fill it with  [vinyl Spackle](https://www.dap.com/dap-products-ph/vinyl-spackling/).

Use a small putty knife to press the filler into the hole, wait a day and then lightly sand it with a fine 220 grit sandpaper or sanding sponge.

Check to see that when it dried it did not shrink leaving a divot, if so repeat the filler process and sand again after it has dried. Now you can paint it white.